# Passing in method to function that calls appropriate get|post|delete as defined by user input

Tags: python-2.7, variables, overriding

I need help with what *think* is called function overriding? Regardless of what it's called here is my issue:

Please note I am not asking for help with the requests module but how to pass in a variable to override or call as specific a class' function.

I have a predefined class that I have to work with and can't modify:

```
class CustomAPI:
...
    def get(some args here)
    def post(some args here)
    def delete(some args here)
...
```

the above is a wrapper that calls the requests module and executes based on what you call:

```
...
my_api = CustomAPI()
my_api.get(some args here)
...
```

what i need help here is how to pass in get|post|delete as variables into another function so that I can make calls as needed.

```
...
api_method = 'get'
do_something_fuction(api_method)
...

do_something_function(api_method):
    response = my_api.api_method(some args here)

...
```

it is the ***api_method*** part that I cant figure out how to pass that value in so that I can call

response = my_api.***get***(some args here) or

response = my_api.***post***(some args here) or

response = my_api.***delete***(some args here) etc...

it would end up being (essentially the equivalent of bash my_api.***$1***(some args here)):

*response = my_api.**api_method**(some args here)*

###### to get around the above

I could do:

```
if api_method = 'get':
    my_api.get(some args here)
elif api_method = 'post':
    my_api.post(some args here)
elif api_method = 'delete':
    my_api.delete(some args here)
```

but I am hoping there is more of a graceful way to do it with less typing as each if statement has like 6 additional lines that are not shown here that are basically repetitive.

Comment: when I try the above in my code I get the following error: **CustomAPI instance has no attribute 'api_method'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I believe the name of what I am trying to do is:

*dynamically instantiate the class method*

```
...
api_method = 'get'
do_something_fuction(api_method)
...

do_something_function(api_method):
    ClassMethod = getattr(my_api, api_method)
    response = ClassMethod(some args here)

...
```

this was my missing piece: ***ClassMethod = getattr(my_api, method)***